# How to change icon of label with mouse entered event?

Tags: java, swing

Here is the code of mouse entered event of label 1 . And the exception is occuring .I have already worked on previous version but I don't why this happening now.

```
private void jLabel1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    ImageIcon n_cig;
    n_cig = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("masterproject/Cfull.png"));
    jLabel1.setIcon(n_cig);

}                                    

private void jLabel1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    

    ImageIcon n_cig;
    n_cig = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("masterproject/No Cigarretes.png"));
    jLabel1.setIcon(n_cig);
}
```

And the exceptions are here

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
at masterproject.design.jButton1ActionPerformed(design.java:384)
at masterproject.design.access$300(design.java:15)
at masterproject.design$3.actionPerformed(design.java:148)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Do you have a folder called masterproject in the folder containing the class file, and are there files called No Cigarretes.png and Cfull.png in that folder?

Comment: Yes masterproject contains all files and masterproject is a package

Comment: Do you have a *folder* called masterproject *in the folder containing the class file*? *Are there files called No Cigarretes.png and Cfull.png in that folder?*

Comment: yes brother I havae masterproject folder and both .png files

Comment: Do you have a folder called masterproject *in the folder containing the class file*?

Comment: On a side note, an undecorated button can do this already.  It accepts different icons for normal view, focused, mouse hover etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you get a **NullPointerException** is because for some reason the image file that you're trying to specify cannot be located. So the **getResource()** method returns a null.

Create a utility function to handle these kind of exception in future

```
public ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                           String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Check using this function that wheather or not you are able to access the image or not